# Random "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." Exceptions

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

We have a web application that occasionally makes HTTPS requests to third party web services. Most of the time these work without issue. However occasionally the application will begin throwing exceptions on each request:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish
                         trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is
                         invalid according to the validation procedure.
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  ...etc...
```

Now the odd part is that when we recycle the web application, the exception stops being thrown. For a while anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined that a library was occasionally setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to a method which did not correctly validate certificates. The reason it seemed random is that certificate validation worked until the library was used and that callback was set.

The solution is to fix the library. And as general rule never globally set `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in production code.